# laravel show multiple data in datatables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, datatables, laravel-permission

I work with laravel spatie permission package and need to show user role for each user in datatables lists. now I  add datatables `addColumn` method:

```
$items = Admin::orderBy('id','DESC');

return DataTables::of($items)
    ->addColumn('role',function(Admin $admin){

        foreach($admin->getRoleNames() as $v){
            return $v;
        }

    })
    ->toJson();
```

this code work and show role name for each user but If user have a two role name(multiple roles) My code not work and show only first role name. ie: for user `test` I have two roles name: `moderator` and `editor` But i see only moderator.

[image]

How to can i show multiple roles name for each user in datatables list?!

Answer (score 0):

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Role');
}
```

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

I think that you should add these methods to your `user` Model and the second one to your `role` Model

Answer (score 0):

I found this and work true:

```
return DataTables::of($items)
    ->addColumn('roles',function(Admin $admin){

        return $admin->roles->pluck('name')->toArray();
    })
    ->toJson();
```